# Non-PHP CGI toolkits that support PHP-like CGI syntax?

Tags: cgi

I have some websites that use extJS with a PHP backend, and we're trying to move away from PHP entirely after a few security incidents.  Due to extJS's license, there are concerns if we'd have to release the server-side code if we modified the javascript, so I'm looking instead to replace the back-end instead.

The calling syntax I'm mostly looking at is how PHP handles arrays.  You might see something like:

```
?array[]=item1;array[]=item2;array=item3[]
```

rather than say, with perl's CGI.pm:

```
?array=item1;array=item2;array=item3
```

Are there CGI libraries for other languages that support this array syntax natively, or should I just hack something together myself?

(it's actually older extJS ... back when they claimed it was released under LGPL, before they posted their take on what LGPL was, which sounded nothing like what I was aware of, but we're not willing to go the legal route, I just haven't had the time to switch to some other JS library)